# 2 models in 1 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I know my question is stupid, but I dont know solution of my problem and can understand  similar questions on stackoverflow.
I doing simple blog.
And when I go to one post in this blog I must see text of post and comments for him. They there are in my datebase, but I dont know how display both.
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom ViewModel for this particular View.  Something like this:

```
public class BlogReaderViewModel
{
    // various fields which exist on either the post or the comments
}
```

Then you'd bind to that ViewModel for the View.  The Controller action would get the Models it needs and build an instance of the ViewModel to pass to the View.

Another option would be to use [a `Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).  It's a generic class which acts as a strongly-typed container for multiple other types.  So the View's Model would be something like this:

```
Tuple<Post, Comments>
```

From an overall design perspective, my biggest recommendation would be to consider how your Models relate to one another and find your "aggregate root."  In the case of a blog post with comments, it sounds like the post should be the aggregate root.  The Model itself should have the comments within it.  Something like this:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that the aggregate root is the parent object and internally knows about its child objects.  You shouldn't have to manually compose those hierarchies of objects every time you want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a ViewModel to represent this View or the data that this view need, for example:

```
public class OrderViewModel {

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateOrder { get; set; }
   public decimal Total { get; set; }
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }

   public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

   // other properties     
}
```

And you shoul use this ViewModel to type your view, for sample (using razor):

```
@model Models.ViewModels.OrderViewModel
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the relationship of the comments in the model.  Usually comments should be a child collection of post.  So in the view you should be able to render the comments with something like this (Razor):

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments) {
    // comments display goes here
}
```

Be sure when you pass the model to the view from the controller that you don't produce an inefficient query.  Make sure that the query gets the comments with the blog, depending on how you are getting your model in the DB.  If you are using EF that would be the "Include" directive, e.g.

```
.Include(p => p.Comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to Create a composite model that represents both groups of data required to render the view, and pass the off each sub model to editor templates on the view itself.